# Help with induction proof , please.

Tags: induction, solution-verification

could someone please help me with the following induction proof.
I'm able to complete a somewhat similar proof where the RHS is equal to an algebraic expression ,but, can't get started with the RHS equal to a summation.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2$$

thanks
           ralph

Comment: Do you already know an algebraic expression for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$?

Answer (score 4):

Can I presume you know what "proof by induction" is?  You "get started" by showing that the statement is true for the 'first case' which, since the sum starts at n= 1, is evaluating both sides for n= 1.  The left side is just the single term $1^3= 1$.  The right side is single number, 1, squared, which is, of course, 1.  They are the same so you have proved the statement for n= 1.

Now, to complete the induction, we need to prove "if the statement is true for n= k then it is also true for n= k+ 1".  On the left side, going from n= k to n= k+ 1 means adding $(k+1)^3= k^3+ 3k^2+ 3k+ 1$.  Assuming that the statement is true for n= k means assuming that the sum of cubes is the same as $(\sum_{i=1}^k i)^2$ so adding $k^3+ 3k^2+ 3k+ 1$ gives $(\sum_{i=1}^k i)^2+ k^3+ 3k^3+ 3k+ 1$.  Is that the same as $(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i)^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Base case :$n=1$√

Hypothesis: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i)^2.$

Step: n+1;

$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$;

$S_{n+1}=S_n+(n+1)$;

RHS:

$(S_{n+1})^2=(S_n+(n+1))^2=$

$(S_n)^2+2(n+1)S_n+(n+1)^2=$

$(S_n)^2 +(n+1)^2(n)+(n+1)^2=$

$(S_n)^2 +(n+1)^2(n+1)=$

$(S_n)^2+(n+1)^3=$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3+(n+1)^3= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i^3$,

where $(S_n)^2=\sum_{i=2}^{n}i^3$ by hypothesis has been used in the second last expression.

Recall: $S_n= \sum_{i=1}^{n}i =(1/2)(n+1)n$.